# Error in mapper_parsing_exception on ElasticSearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, mongoose, backend

The server is started on port 3000.

> Error creating mapping[mapper_parsing_exception] No handler for type
>   [string] declared on field [category] ::
>   {"path":"/products/_mapping/product","query":{},"body":"{\"product\":{\"properties\":{\"category\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"name\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"price\":{\"type\":\"double\"},\"image\":{\"type\":\"string\"}}}}","statusCode":400,"response":"{\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"mapper_parsing_exception\",\"reason\":\"No
>   handler for type [string] declared on field
>   [category]\"}],\"type\":\"mapper_parsing_exception\",\"reason\":\"No
>   handler for type [string] declared on field
>   [category]\"},\"status\":400}"}

connected to database

Indexed 120 documents

//code

```
Product.createMapping(function(err, mapping){
if(err){
    console.log("Error creating mapping"+ err);
}else{
    console.log("Mapping Cretaed");
    console.log(mapping);
}
});

var stream = Product.synchronize();
var count = 0;

stream.on('data', function(){
    count++;
});
stream.on('close', function(){
    console.log("Indexed " + count + "documents");
});
stream.on('error', function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

New code added to explain what product is

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;
var mongoosastic = require("mongoosastic");

//Schema
var ProductSchema = new Schema({
    category : {
        type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : 'Category'
    },
    name : String,
    price : Number,
    image : String 
});
ProductSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
    hosts : [
    'localhost:9200'
    ]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

Comment: Have you got the correct solution? I am encountering the same issue. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mapping you're trying to create, you have a type `string` which has been deprecated in ES 5.x. You need to use `text` or `keyword` instead.

Your mapping should look like this instead:

```
{
  "product": {
    "properties": {
      "category": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "price": {
        "type": "double"
      },
      "image": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

The issue comes from the fact that as of June 26th, 2018, [mongoosastic 4.4.1 doesn't support ES5](https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic/issues/436). One workaround is to modify your mongo schema like this

```
category: { 
  type: String,
  es_type: 'keyword'
}
price: { 
  type: Number,
  es_type: 'double'
}
name: { 
  type: String,
  es_type: 'text'
}
image: { 
  type: String,
  es_type: 'text'
}
```